# why is my function not taking prop value?

Tags: javascript

I have made a function to assign css style easily. but my function is not taking second value of prop in function.

I have tried everything I know.

```
<div id="obj"></div>
<script>
let obj=document.getElementById('obj');
animate=(element,prop,value)=>element.style.prop=value+'px';
animate(obj,'top',100);
</script>
```

Comment: Tacking on a string after a period doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) for dynamic property names.

```
animate = (element,prop,value) => element.style[prop] = value + 'px';
```

**Note**:setting `top` will never work if the position is default to check set it `absolute`. Below is example

```js
let obj=document.getElementById('obj');
animate=(element,prop,value)=>element.style[prop]=value+'px';
animate(obj,'top',100);
```

```css
#obj{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="obj">Something</div>
```